# How to limit the Kendo grid row selection?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a requirement in which I have to restrict the max selection of rows in Kendo grid to 5, user can select max 5 records in Kendo grid.
Any body have any idea or sample code.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo doesn't have an out of the box support for max selected rows. Use the `Change` event to catch an array of selected rows and de-select extra rows. The basic working code is as follows where the user can select 5 rows at max.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    change: function(e) {
       var items = e.sender.select();
        items.each(function(i, e) {
          /* allows user to select 5 rows max */
          if (i > 4) {
            $(e).removeClass("k-state-selected");
          }
        });
     }
});
```

Check out the demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imsangram/s2fw70d8/1/).